# Controlling shapes in PowerBI map

Tags: powerbi, tableau-api, geospatial, shapefile, spotfire

I tried to display provinces in PowerBI map but there are provinces / regions that cannot be found, such as Dipaculao of the Philippines and Riau Islands of Indonesia.

I tried to search in google and bing to build the dictionary, but there are still such missing regions.

Do you know what is the right input dictionary of provinces to get the correct picture. Or do you know if there is a mechanism to load shape files in PowerBI as we can do in spotfire or tableau?

[Error regions in the PowerBI map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhZrE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can bring in you own shape maps into the visual in Power BI, these have to be in TopoJson Format, a good place to start would be [here](https://github.com/deldersveld/topojson/tree/master/countries/philippines) for a map of the Philippines. From your issue it looks like the province/region is not being mapped correctly, so in the back ground your dataset with the province/region name isn't being connected to shape file. I have had this issue before in the shape map, due to translation errors and the shape map being out of date with naming and regional changes.

To get round this, I checked the topojson map using an online editor [here](https://mapshaper.org/), adjusted the metadata in the editor and loaded the adjusted map into the Power BI Shape map visual to see it map the data correctly.

Hope that helps